# Does anybody know how to updateOne MongoDB collection using stepzen schema?

Tags: mongodb, graphql

I've figured out how to read and create a MongoDB collection entry using stepzen. However, I can't for the life of me, figure out how to update an entry. Does anybody know? This is what I think the schema might look like.

```
type Mutation {
  updateAthleteById(
    dataSource: String! = "Cluster0"
    database: String! = "training"
    collection: String! = "athletes"
    athleteId: ID!
    updateFields: UpdateAthlete
  ): Result
    @rest(
      method: POST
      endpoint: "https://eu-west-2.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/$appid/endpoint/data/v1/action/updateOne"
      headers: [
        { name: "access-control-request-headers", value: "*" }
        { name: "api-key", value: "$apikey" }
      ]
      configuration: "mongodb"
      postbody: """
      {
        "filter": {
          "_id": "{{.Get "athleteId"}}"
        },
        "update": {
          "$set": "{{.Get "updateFields"}}"
        }
      }
      """
    )
}
```

However, it's not working so I must be doing it wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
type Mutation {
  updateAthleteById(
    athleteId: String
    updateFields: String
  ): Result
    @rest(
      method: POST
      endpoint: "https://eu-west-2.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/app/$appid/endpoint/data/v1/action/updateOne"
      headers: [
        { name: "access-control-request-headers", value: "*" }
        { name: "api-key", value: "$apikey" }
      ]
      configuration: "mongodb"
      postbody: """
      {
        "dataSource": "Cluster0",
        "database": "training",
        "collection": "athletes",
        "filter": {
          "_id": { "$oid": "{{.Get "athleteId"}}"}
        },
        "update": {
          "$set": {"name": "{{.Get "updateFields"}}"}
        }
      }
      """
    )
}
```

For those that is looking and come across this, it seems that you would need to structure the postbody and then pass all the input arguments inside. Make sure you add this to your config so StepZen won't append the arguments to the url:

```
configurationset:
  - configuration:
      name: "mongodb"
      stepzen.queryextensionguard: true <-----
```

For Int just do "$oid": {{.Get "athleteId"}}